# How can I fix the 'bash: 5: command not found' error when using backticks in Jest test function?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Using backticks in test function of jest causes to skip the test.

I used jest library for testing "fizzBuzz" function. But the test get an error. The error is "bash: 5: command not found.". I realized that this error is related to backticks. How can I get rid of this error?

```
const fizzBuzz = (num) => {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i % 15 === 0) result.push('FizzBuzz');
        else if (i % 3 === 0) result.push('Fizz');
        else if (i % 5 === 0) result.push('Buzz');
        else result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
};
test('Calling fizzbuzz with `5` prints out 5 statements', () => {
    fizzBuzz(5);

    expect(console.log.mock.calls.length).toEqual(5);
});
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
});

afterEach(() => {
    console.log.mockRestore();
});
```